# What is control-label in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to find it inside Bootstrap 3 [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/css/), but only found how to use it while there is no clear explanation regarding the functionality of `control-label`.

Googling also don't give me any clue, as many that I found only said to simply put in there, without explaining why we need to put in there.

Also please bear with me if my question seems silly, as I just really started using Bootstrap 3 and CSS, so many of things are new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC `control-label` is a bootstrap CSS class that ties labels to the validation on controls. You can check the [Bootstrap documentation on form validation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) as to the purpose of this class.